# How to start the activity inside below code?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to start the activity inside below code?

```
adaptor.AddFragmentView((i, v, b) =>
     {
         View rootView = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TrafficReports, v, false);

         return rootView;                       
     }
 );
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? You want to start an activity or fragment inside or outside another activity or fragment?

Comment: Please @SathishkumarTamilselvi can you mark my post as the answer? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
adaptor.AddFragmentView((i, v, b) =>
{
   View rootView = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TrafficReports, v, false);
   rootView.Context?.StartActivity(typeof(ActivityX));

   return rootView;
});
```

Comment: This is very useful.. i got the result that what i expected .. thank you.

Comment: Please @SathishkumarTamilselvi can you mark my post as the answer? thank you.